# Can't set height to 100% on flex child

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I have a fairly straight forward layout in mind, and this involves my body (essentially the content of the page after header) being at least 100% height. This works fine on desktop breakpoints, but as soon as I switch to a mobile breakpoint (which sets container to flex-direction to column), I can't seem to make the body element 100% height. I've tried using 100vh, and it works, but then screws up the layout of the desktop view. Every parent of this body element has a height bigger than it/100%.

I am using flexbox, styled-components, and React.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Body CSS:

```
  font-family: 'FuturaBold';
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color: black;

  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media (max-width: ${Breakpoints.tablet}) {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
```

Parent CSS:

```
  min-height: 100% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  background-color: ${Colours.dark};

  display: flex;

  @media (max-width: ${Breakpoints.tablet}) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHSL4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your approaches.

Set `height: 100vh` in media query only. This wouldn't screw things up in desktop view